# How to safely parse the Date HTTP header in javascript

Tags: javascript, http, date, datetime

If I use `Date.parse()`, am I "nearly guaranteed" to be able to parse what comes at my program?

In [Mozilla's entry for Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), they write:

> Given a string representing a time, parse() returns the time value. It accepts the [RFC2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) / IETF date syntax (RFC2822 Section 3.3), e.g. "Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT".

My own server returns `Sun, 24 May 2015 05:37:13 GMT`.

Trouble is, [Wikipedia tells me that the `Date` header follows the RFC 7131](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). Now, [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1) and while they seem to be saying the same thing (although 7231 is broader), I was wondering...

If I use `Date.parse()`, am I "nearly guaranteed" to be able to parse what comes at my program? I am happy to assume that the server isn't running in a time vacuum.

Comment: You shouldn't "be able to parse what comes" but instead "know what format you receive and parse it". What kind of server doesn't have one constant date format? If you know it then what's the problem?

Comment: Hummm... dod you read my question? I pointed to all of the RFC. When you talk about Internet standards, there are a lot of SHOULD, COULD, etc. I don't know in advance what server I will connect to.

Comment: You don't know in advance what server you will connect to? How is that even possible? How do you know what kind of response you'll get (json, xml, etc.)? That's sounds like an unreal problem to me. Each server is implemented independently. And once you start looking at real implementations you'll find out that there really is no such thing as standards.

Comment: Are you writing a JS framework? Then just force servers to use a format you want. Simple as that.

Comment: @freakish If you force the servers to use a different format in the headers, you'd be violating the requirement that it follows RFC 7231. Instead, this would have to be done somewhere in the application code or through a new header.

Comment: @faraz First of all, I've never said to use different format. You can force them to use RFC 7231. Secondly noone really cares about RFC XXXX (put your random number here). You can argue that they should but the reality is as it is. Most (if not all) servers violate some RFC rules. And since OP doesn't know which server he is going to connect to then let's stick to the reality.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TL;DR If you're getting back a [new or old RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1) compliant string, it will parse on most modern browsers since they all have very similar and ***insanely*** flexible parsing rules:

```
new Date('Sun, 24 May 2015 05:37:13 GMT')
new Date('2015 GMT 24 05:37:13 May')
// => Sun May 24 2015 01:37:13 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

If you need a 100% guarantee across any compliant ECMAScript implementation, you'll need to use your application code to convert the timestamp to the [ISO 8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601): **`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`**

Remember though the timezone may shift according to the user's location.

---

ECMAScript only specifies the following format for dates:

> ECMAScript defines a string interchange format for date-times based
> upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 Extended Format. The format is
> as follows: **`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`**

Source: http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15

Regarding `Date.parse`:

> If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall
> back to any implementation-specific heuristics or
> implementation-specific date formats.

Source: http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.4.2

With modern browser implementations, the following rules generally apply:

- `month/day/year`, `month-day-year` for short dates
- Months and days can be 1 or 2 digits
- Years with only two digits must be >= 70
- For spelled out dates, the year month and day can be in any order anywhere (you'll see what I mean by anywhere later): `January 1 2000`, `1 January 2000`, `2000 1 January`
- Months may be abbreviated to three characters (I believe IE allows for two)
- JavaScript will override invalid days of the week
- Hours minutes and seconds are separated by colons: '10:20:30', '10:20', '10:' are valid
- You can specify 'AM' and 'PM' anywhere, but if you're wrong or redundant you'll get `NaN` or an invalid date error
- You can specify a timezone string (e.g. 'EST', 'EDT', 'GMT') anywhere

"Anywhere" truly means "anywhere": you can jumble the crap out of the components. The following insanity works, for example...

```
new Date('PM Jan EST 2015 1 10:00')
new Date('2015 1 10:00 Jan EST PM')
// => Thu Jan 01 2015 10:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

...which is why you're *nearly* guaranteed for those dates to parse.

Sources:

- V8: https://github.com/v8/v8-git-mirror/blob/master/test/mjsunit/date-parse.js
- Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse
- WebKit: https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/LayoutTests/js/date-parse-test-expected.txt, https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WTF/wtf/DateMath.cpp (what a namespace!)
- MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/k4w173wk%28v=vs.94%29.aspx